# Result of a Select query into another table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

In Windows form application, I want to add The Result of a Select SQL Query into another table.

- The input pid (textBox1.text) is a integer no.
- When running this application, I am getting the message "Product Added" but actually its not.
- This the code behind the button click, I think the SQL query is wrong somewhere. please help

  ```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=HOME;Initial   
                             Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into list (pname, pprice)
    (select pname, pprice from products where pid='" +textBox1.Text+"')", con);
          MessageBox.Show("Product Added");
    con.Close();
    }
  ```

Comment: You don't need the parentheses around the `select`.  Although it works in this case, it can cause problems sometimes.

Comment: actually its not working :(

Comment: If you remove the where clause, are any rows inserted then?

Comment: What your error or Is it simply not inserting data? Also, you need to use parameters in your query instead of concatenations.

Comment: ya no errors . its simply not inserting data.

Comment: @DineshSoni . . . Then there are probably no matches to the `where` clause.  Usually, `id`s are integers so it is surprising that you are enclosing it in parentheses, for instance.

Comment: data is present in the database to execute as: (table)
pid        pname        pprice
1001     abc             100

Comment: and also removing parenthesis not helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
  SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter();
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=HOME;Initial   
                           Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True");
  
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into list (pname, pprice)
  select pname, pprice from products where pid='" +textBox1.Text+"'", con);
  con.Open();
  SDA.SelectCommand = cmd;
  SDA.Fill(dt);
  con.Close();
  MessageBox.Show("Product Added");
  
  }
```

You made following mistakes in your code

> 1 : you open connection before creating  of sqlcommand object
>
> 2:  you did not write code to execute the query properly
>
> 3:  you also put parenthesis before the select statement

**Note:**
Make Sure textBox1.Text is not null or empty  also you should use paramterize query